# In SBT, Is there a way of just downloading the top-level dependencies?

Tags: sbt

I have an SBT project which pulls in dependencies. I only want to pull in the direct dependencies - not any transitive dependencies. I'd like to find the filename of the dependency that's pulled in, so that I can copy it somewhere.

e.g. given a `build.sbt` file with the following contents:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.4.28.v20200408"
```

I would like to know where is the jetty-server jar on the file system.

I have tried adding the following to my `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val mytaskKey: TaskKey[Unit] = TaskKey[Unit]("mytask")

def mytask: Def.Setting[Task[Unit]] = mytaskKey := {
  val updateReport = update.value
  updateReport.allFiles foreach { f =>
    println(f)
  }
}

mytask
```

When I run this, I get a full list of dependencies:

```
/Users/dylan/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.10/lib/scala-library.jar
/Users/dylan/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.28.v20200408/jetty-server-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
/Users/dylan/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.10/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/Users/dylan/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.10/lib/scala-reflect.jar
/Users/dylan/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.12/1.0.6/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar
/Users/dylan/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar
/Users/dylan/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.12/jansi-1.12.jar
```

I don't want that full list - I just want the jetty jar. i.e.

```
/Users/dylan/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.28.v20200408/jetty-server-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
```

How might I get this list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is with either `intransitive()` or `notTransitive()` classifiers. It's documented [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies).